# GeoJSON output not showing with FORMATOPTION "storage=stream"

Tags: geojson, wfs, mapserver

I am trying to get MapServer to serve WFS layers as GeoJSON, using `FORMATOPTION "storage=stream"`, but I only get an empty response in the browser.

It works if I have `FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=filesystem"` instead of "stream" set in the OUTPUTFORMAT block. If I test the same string (with `outputformat=geojson&`) with mapserv on the command line, I get the JSON output, just not in the browser.

I am running MapServer 6.4.1, and GDAL 1.11.1.

What could I be missing?

I also have GeoJSON listed in wfs_getfeature_formatlist in the METADATA section.

The outputformat block:

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "geojson"
        DRIVER "OGR/GEOJSON"
        FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=stream"
        FORMATOPTION "FORM=simple"
        FORMATOPTION "LCO:COORDINATE_PRECISION=3"
        FORMATOPTION "LCO:WRITE_BBOX=YES"
        MIMETYPE "application/json"
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was using FastCGI. With MapServer 6.4.1, OGR outputs don't work in FastCGI mode when STORAGE is set to stream: https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/pull/4858

Using CGI, I got GeoJSON output to work in streaming mode.

MapServer-6.4.2 has a work-around for FastCGI support.  Set

```
    FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=memory"
```

There is a proper fix using gdal-2.0 [according to this post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OGR-GeoJSON-stream-output-not-working-with-FCGI-td5186516.html).